# SAS code - sum of last N rows for every row

Tags: sas, proc-sql, do-loops, datastep

I have a dataset like this for each ID;

| Months | ID | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-07-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2018-08-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2018-09-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2018-10-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2018-11-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2018-12-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-03-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019-04-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-05-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-06-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-07-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019-08-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-09-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-10-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2019-11-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-12-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-07-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-08-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-10-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-04-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2018-07-01 | 2 | 0 |
| ....... | ....... | ....... |

(Similar values for each ID)

I want a dataset like this;

| Months | ID | Number | Sum_Next_6Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-07-01 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| 2018-08-01 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| 2018-09-01 | 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2018-10-01 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2018-11-01 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2018-12-01 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2019-02-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2019-03-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2019-04-01 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2019-05-01 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2019-06-01 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2019-07-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2019-08-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2019-09-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2019-10-01 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2019-11-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-12-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-04-01 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-07-01 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2020-08-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-09-01 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2020-10-01 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 2020-11-01 | 1 | 1 | Nan |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 | 0 | Nan |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 0 | Nan |
| 2021-02-01 | 1 | 1 | Nan |
| 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1 | Nan |
| 2021-04-01 | 1 | 0 | Nan |
| 2018-07-01 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... |

If there is no 6 months left then this values should be Nan.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi! What code have you tried?  What is "Nan" - SAS doesn't have "Nan", do you mean missing value? Or is that a text column?

Comment: Hi! Yes I meant missing value. I was trying to solve with proc sql but I should have tried do loop. It's solved thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data want(drop = i n);
   set have curobs = c nobs = nobs;
   Sum_Next_6Numbers = 0;
   
   do p = c + 1 to 6 + c;

      if p > nobs then do;
         Sum_Next_6Numbers = .; leave;
      end;

      set have(keep = Number ID rename = (Number = n id = i)) point = p;

      if id ne i then do;
         Sum_Next_6Numbers = .; leave;
      end;

      Sum_Next_6Numbers + n;
   end;
run;
```